# Eclipse plugin to automatically copy the variables to the clipboard when clicking on them

Tags: eclipse, clipboard

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that can allow to automatically copy the variables to the clipboard when clicking on them in Eclipse.

E.g. if I click like this:

[image]

The clipboard should then contain `patients_directories`.

If possible, it should work for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: So... a plugin that will remove the need for a second click and Ctrl-C? Why?

Comment: @generalcrispy Minimizing keyboard use. I am trying to code as hands-free as possible (moving cursor + clicking is hands-free as I use a hands-free mouse, namely SmartNAV). Double clicking means I have to switch click mode in the dwell clicking software, copying means one more voice command. I could do one voice command to copy the variable name by sending a few shortcuts but a single left click would be much easier. More info: http://francky.me/publications.php#mouse2012

Answer (score 0):

There is no Eclipse Plugin that could help you archive that.

My way out was to buy a Logitech MX Master:

[image]

Thanks to that I can:

1. **Show/Hide Desktop**: Win + D
2. **Copy**: Ctrl + C
3. **Paste**: Ctrl + V

There are many mouse out there from many brands that could provide even more options.

I have a colleague with a Razer that has 12 buttons and he saves into those button about 10 different SQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to Linux - we have the traditional ctrl-c/v copy/paste, but also X11 allows you to simply select some text and then middle click to paste.  Even works in console only mode when using `gpm`.

Looks like there is a (older) utility for Windows that will enable similar functionality -

http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/

Also appears that you may be able to tweak some Windows settings to get the same functionality -

http://www.jarte.com/help_new/jarte_options.html#middle_mouse_paste

Comment: Thanks, "select some text and then middle click to paste." is more work than I would like: I'd prefer to only have to click on the variable with left click and without having to select the variable

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt IIRC Eclipse is good about selecting when you double-click on something, and pays attention to "borders" like white space, special characters (equal sign, etc) and quote marks.  Of course, that could just be the way X11/xorg is working for me.  Don't have a Windows or Mac machine to test on.